# Node.js socket _writableState is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have some code that should close the socket, but instead causes an error: (with NODE_DEBUG=net)

```
NET: 5482 onread undefined 32 7 39
NET: 5482 got data
NET: 5482 _read
ATL 0  // these are output from the program

3
ATL

net.js:425
  if (this._writableState.finished)
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'finished' of undefined
  at Socket.destroySoon (net.js:425:26)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/crunch/js_relay_tools/atprox.js:45:4)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
  at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)
```

This socket is stored in an array, but I don't think that it should make a difference. I have tried Socket.end (which I am using right now), and Socket.destroySoon, but neither work, and have similar errors (both dealing with the writable state of the socket being undefined).

Closing code:

```
var sx = sa[parseInt(b[0])]; // get socket from array
var cf = sx==undefined?function (){sock.write("#E,no such socket")}:(sx.close || sx.end || function () {}); // get close/end function
cf(); // call close function
sa[parseInt(b[0])] = undefined; // clear array entry so socket cannot be closed again
```

What makes this even more interesting is that I have similar code in another place in the script, and it works fine, working with the same array. I have confirmed that the socket is actually open and able to send and receive data, but not close.

TL;DR: Socket._writableState is undefined, but I can still read and write to the socket, and I cannot close/end it

Is it a bug, or did I mess up?